# Make a working Windows installation from just the OS files

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, partitioning

Having a bit of a nightmare this morning.

I've got 5 machines to setup. I've set one of them up perfectly, then I tried to take an image using Acronis Disk Director.

However... I've managed to break everything in the process.

Here are the steps I took in Disk Director:

1. No option to "Clone Basic Disk" on the working local HDD
2. Converted the local HDD from GPT to MBR
3. Used "Clone Basic Disk" to copy this HDD to an external HDD
4. Tried to boot the local machine... `ERROR: No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed`

Since then I've tried to follow a few guides. I've tried to create the partitions using `diskpart` but nothing has worked. I've now got a drive with 3 partitions - 2 unallocated partitions (~229mb total) and 1 healthy ~490Gb partition containing the OS files (which I can still view/access, I haven't touched that partition at any point).

The guides I've followed are for UEFI... but they seem to mention steps that I can't see like `when you press F8 to enter the boot menu, you'll see two options to boot into Windows 7 - make sure you select the UEFI option`. I don't have anything like that!

What steps do I need to take to set the right "System" and "Reserved" partitions up, and make my Windows 7 drive bootable again? I've got the Windows 7 CD that I used to install the OS in the first place but obviously the "repair" function doesn't work because it doesn't see any OS.

Help..! :)

Comment: You need to fix your MBR. Hirens boot cd has a tool called mbrfix. you need to run this.

Comment: Did you also convert the booting drive to MBR? You might need to change your BIOS settings and disable UEFI.

Comment: @LPChip will Hirens set up the partitions for me at the right size etc? Or will I need to do those first, then run mbrfix?

Comment: @Spokey I've checked the BIOS (it's a HP machine.. menu options seem fairly limited) but I can't find any option to disable UEFI. The HDD *is* listed as UEFI though.

Comment: @dunc mbrfix will only fix the mbr. It will not make partitions etc.

Comment: Windows can't boot from MBR on a UEFI based system. The disk has to be GPT (or at least the boot partition).

Comment: What's the process then @Spokey? Convert the drive to GPT, then...?

Comment: I don't see any other options if you can't change the booting settings. You already made a backup so check that your data is safe first and try converting back to GPT. There are tools out there that will allow you to convert without any data loss.

Comment: @dunc I'm more the linux guy. Just a hint, I usually copied disks using dd there. Is that a possible solution? Did you check that? And isn't there a windows automated installation toolkit from Microsoft, or is already software installed?

Comment: @Spokey I can convert it back to GPT easily enough, Disk Director will do that without losing data. I just don't know what to do then. The guides I followed for UEFI stuff for example had me booting to my Windows DVD, entering the terminal, then running commands in diskpart... but nothing seems to have worked.

Comment: Have you done anything else to those partitions other than changing them to MBR?

Comment: @Spokey Since then, yes. I pratted about trying to get them working - so I reformatted them as EFI, then FAT32, etc etc. They'll need to be fully rebuilt.

Comment: I see. That changes things a little. Have you already tried changing the active boot partition to the drive with the windows installation? You can do that with diskpart.